# bisectors in a right triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, bisection

Given right triangle $ABC$, $AC=8$, $BC=6$ and $\angle C = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

$BP$ and $CR$ – bisectors of triangle $ABC$, intersecting at the point $L$.

Need to find:

1) periods in which these bisectors divide point $L$.

2) the area of the quadrilateral $APLR$.

How to solve these problems? Unfortunately so far, no ideas. Where to start?

Comment: Maybe $\measuredangle C=90^{\circ}$?

Comment: Yes, of course. I corrected the post

Answer (score 1):

[image]

\begin{align} 
A&=(6,8),\quad B=(0,0),\quad C=(0,8)
,\\
a&=|BC|=6
,\quad
b=|AC|=8
,\quad
c=|AB|=10.
\end{align}

$L$ is incenter of $\triangle ABC$,
$P$ and $Q$ are the feet points of the bisectors,
\begin{align} 
L&=\frac{aA+bB+cC}{a+b+c}=(4,\,2)
,\\
P&=\frac{aA+cC}{a+c}=(6,\,3)
,\\
Q&=\frac{aA+bB}{a+b}=(\tfrac{18}7,\,\tfrac{24}7)
,\\
|BP|&=|B-P|=3\,\sqrt5
,\quad |LP|=|L-P|=\sqrt5
,\\
|CQ|&=|C-Q|=\tfrac{24}7\sqrt2
,\quad |LQ|=|L-Q|=
\tfrac{10}7\sqrt2
.
\end{align}

By [the shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula)
for the area of a simple polygon whose vertices are described by their Cartesian coordinates,

\begin{align} 
S_{AQLP}
&=\tfrac12(
A_x\,Q_y+Q_x\,L_y+L_x\,P_y+P_x\,A_y-(A_y\,Q_x+Q_y\,L_x+L_y\,P_x+P_y\,A_x)
)=\tfrac{75}{7}
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

By Pythagoras theorem we obtain $AB=10$.

Now, $AP:BC=10:6=5:3$, which gives $AP=5$ and $PC=3$.

Also, $AR:RB=8:6=4:3,$ which gives $RB=\frac{30}{7}$.

Thus, $CL:LR=6:\frac{30}{7}=7:5$ and $PL:LB=3:6=1:2$ and 1) is done!

$S_{\Delta ABC}=\frac{8\cdot6}{2}=24$.

Hence, $S_{\Delta APB}=\frac{5}{8}\cdot24=15$.

Now, $S_{\Delta CBR}=\frac{3}{7}\cdot24=\frac{72}{7}$.

Thus, $S_{\Delta LBR}=\frac{5}{12}\cdot\frac{72}{7}=\frac{30}{7}$.

Id est, $S_{APLR}=15-\frac{30}{7}=\frac{75}{7}$ and we are done!